# Finding Generators of an Ideal Over Number Field?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory

Is there any way or algorithm to find generators of an ideal over number field? (A algorithm that can be implemented and not expensive)

Comment: How is the ideal described?

Comment: Do you want a single generator (i.e. test for principality) or any number of generators?